# Recursive JPA entity relationship with another composed entity

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have these 2 entities called Owner and Folder.
Every folder(s) belong to an owner.
Inside a folder, we can have subfolder(s), and so on.

Owner Entity

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "FOLDER_ID", nullable = false)
private Set<Folder> folders = new HashSet<>();

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

// Getters and setters
```

Folder Entity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_FOLDER_ID")
private Folder parent;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Folder> children = new HashSet<>(); // recursive

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

// Getters and setter
```

An owner named Steve has a folder called mainFolder with a subFolder inside.
When trying to persist the owner, I hit backref issue.
I believe this is due to the subfolder does not know who is its owner.
Question is, since subFolder is inside a mainFolder and mainFolder belongs to Steve, that makes subFolder belongs to Steve as well. 
What JPA relationship can I use for this issue?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Folder mainFolder = new Folder();
    Folder subFolder = new Folder();

    mainFolder.setName("Main Folder");
    mainFolder.getChildren().add(subFolder);
    subFolder.setName("SubFolder");
    subFolder.setParent(mainFolder);

    Owner owner = new Owner();
    owner.setName("Steve");
    owner.getFolders().add(mainFolder);

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(owner); // backrefs error when trying to persist
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Exception log

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or   transient value: entity.Folder._foldersBackref
at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:72)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:290)
```

I am using hibernate with H2.

Comment: There is no `_foldersBackref` field in the code you posted. Are we supposed to guess how it is defined and mapped?

Comment: that is not a field, it is a backreference issue due to the recursive in folder entity.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using? I've never seen it used a _xxxBackref field before.

Comment: Hibernate 3, but i dont think it is related to the Hibernate version.
Any hibernate version will give you the same problem, I guess. Must be some missing relationship problems.

Comment: Any JPA experts here to help?